How to change Version property in a wix toolset project based on teamcity build.number
Using Teamcity, I previously used a Visual Studio (sln) build runner to build my solution.  This solution includes a Wix v4 installer.  Using the sln runner I could add /p:Version=%build.number% as a command line parameter and the build.number would then be included in the msi filename upon build.
Since the sln build runner is now deprecated and I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 I am trying to change the build runner to use devenv.  But the devenv runner doesn't support the /p switch so how do I now pass the build.number to the build?  I have tried /ProjectConfig "Version=%build.number%" as a command line switch but this doesn't change the version in the filename, instead leaving it as 1.0.0.0 which is the default $(Version) property in the project file.
